# How to automate mongodb backup from openshift pod?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3, openshift, mongodump

Some time ago a create a projet with Openshift V3 using "Node.js + MongoDB" starter kit.

It work fine and now I want to automate the mongo db backup. 
I find a lot of Node.js module that I can use to do it very easily but they need "mongodump".

In the Node.js pod, there is no "mongodump" ! ARRGGGGGG

I found no "good" solution :

- [Multiple containers in one pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565569/multiple-containers-in-one-pod) : not so easy and not good
- copy mongodump binary into my Node.js Pod : easy but not good
- using something like  [mongo-backup-to-s3](https://github.com/bradoyler/mongo-backup-to-s3) / [mongo-dump-stream](https://github.com/punkave/mongo-dump-stream) but it's deprecated
- what else ?

I have no more idea. Could you please help me ?

Comment: Why do you need it as a node module?

Comment: i am not. i am open to any solution.

Comment: My solution this far : copy mongodup binary into my Node.js Pod dans use s3-mongo-backup nodejs module.  Working great.