# how to complicated ruby on rails application to openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, openshift

I have one ruby on rails application and I would like to migrate it to upshift.
The ruby on rails application have some background services like:
1. qpid
2. umb
3. delayed_jobs

And we know openshift suggests that one container one process
What Can I do for this part?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can multiple containers in a pod on `OpenShift`.
Refer [Multiple containers in one pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565569/multiple-containers-in-one-pod) for more details.